# Calculate number of overlapping intervals at x

Tags: python, range, intervals

Let's say I have a number of intervals on the same x axis. How do I get the number of intervals for a specific x value?

I search for an easy solution with a python package.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If range is an input list, and point is where you want to find number of intervals.

Example: `ranges = [[0,5],[3,6],[-2,0],[4,10]]`  , `point = 3`

This might be a simple code which returns the number of intervals for a point.

```
>>> def count_intervals(ranges,point):
...   count = 0
...   for range in ranges:
...     if range[0] <= point and range[1] >= point:
...       count += 1
...   return count
```

Few example outputs

```
>>> print(count_intervals([[0,5],[3,6],[-2,0],[4,10]],3))
2
>>> print(count_intervals([[0,5],[3,6],[5,12],[4,5],[7,13]],8))
2
>>> print(count_intervals([[0,5],[3,6],[5,12],[4,9],[7,13]],8))
3
```